# Как связать JQuery Notes и LightBox?

Tags: php, jquery, плагин, lightbox

Добрый день! Помогите пожалуйста! Есть плагины для `jQuery`, первый (`jQquery Notes`) формирует подсказки на [изображении](http://jquery-notes.rydygel.de/samples.php), а второй выводит полноразмерные изображения (`LightBox`). По отдельности оба плагина работают. Как связать их вместе, чтобы я мог наносить текстовые метки на полноразмерном изображении в `LightBox`.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, что конфликтуют библиотеки плагинов. Иногда помогает [jQuery.noConflict()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: Вобщем я сделал некое подобие функции, где указываются параметры для jQuery Notes:
     function setParams() {
    $('.lb-image').jQueryNotes({   

    });
  }

Потом в lightbox.js сделал следующее:
    Lightbox.prototype.showImage = function() {
      var $lightbox;
      ...
      $lightbox.find('.lb-image').fadeIn('slow');
      
      setParams(); 
   
      this.updateNav();
      ....
    };

Теперь все создается, как нужно с одним НО: кнопки для создания подсказок не работают :(